# Is there a way to add a hook on Firebase functions error

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have a Firebase project with cloud functions and i'd like to be able to add a hook when there's an error (like sending a slack message with the error log).

I think it's not possible because this is basic nodejs errors, but if someone knows a way, it would be nice to share it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible in function code. You should capture all errors in your function code and deal with them accordingly.

You may also want to look into StackDriver and its [notification options](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/support/notification-options), which will let you view errors from functions in a more systematic way than just viewing the log in the console.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i'll look on StackDriver